# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlib3'

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6

Im New to Python, trying to code a  **webscraper**. Launching my  script got an error.
Please can you help

```
julien@julien-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-15IWL:~/Bureau$ python3 Paris.py
```

Error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlib3'
>
> julien@julien-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-15IWL:~/Bureau$ python3 -m pip list
>
> setproctitle (1.1.10)
> urllib3 (1.26.4)
> vboxapi (1.0)
> virtualenv (15.1.0)
>
> #!/usr/bin/env python3

Code:

```
# import libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urlib3
# fetch the friend-list from LiveJournal
urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is `urllib3`, you are importing `urlib3`.

Use `import urllib3`.